# Route params not getting sent to ExpressJS API

Tags: javascript, angularjs, express, mongoose

I'm scratching my head on this.

I'm running an expressjs site with angularjs as my front-end resource, and my problem is that I've set up my API to query my datastore with a parameterized query. When I hit the route, the parameter is not appearing in my angularjs resource query, so I end up just getting the entire data set instead of one object by id.

/api/index.js:

```
var _getSingleRequest = function(req, res, next)
{
    models.Request
        .findOne({'_id': req.body.id})
        .exec(function(err, request){
            if(err) return res.send(500, err);
            if(!request) return res.send(404, new Error("Request not found"));

            res.send(request);
        });
};
...
return {
    _getSingleRequest: getSingleRequest
}
```

/server.js

```
...
var api = require('./api');
app.get('/api/request/:id', api.getSingleRequest);
...
```

/public/js/controllers/controller.js

```
...
function Request($scope, $resource, $routeParams, Request)
{
    $scope.request = Request.query({_id : $routeParams.id});
    ...
}
...
```

/public/js/services/services.js

```
services.Request = function($resource)
    {
        return $resource('/api/request/:id', {id:'@id'}, {'get': {method:'GET', isArray: true}});
    }
```

console

```
Mongoose: requests.find({}) { fields: undefined, safe: undefined, sort: [ [ 'requestedDate', 1 ] ] }
GET /api/request?_id=51b8cc2a06859bd418000001 304 179ms
```

it appears that the get request is coming through properly, but in the Mongoose query there are no parameters being passed.

what simple mistake am I making, and what other information can I post to help me figure out how to get out of the infinite loop of banging my head on the wall?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `Request` function, you're passing `_id`:

```
Request.query({_id : $routeParams.id});
               ^^^
```

But in your service, you're expecting `id`:

```
$resource('/api/request/:id', {id:'@id'}
                                   ^^^
```

That will generate requests looking like this (which is also what your log says):

```
/api/request/?_id=XXX
```

But your backend is expecting this:

```
/api/request/XXX
```

Comment: that did it. i could have sworn that I had it set up that way, and it was still problematic, but the likely case is that I wasn't and voodoo isn't real.

thanks robert!

Answer (score 0):

`req.body.id` is for the request body, not route parameters, which come from the request URI. You want `req.params.id`

Comment: I'm still getting the same readout on the console, and it's still pulling all requests:

Mongoose: requests.find({}) { fields: undefined, safe: undefined, sort: [ [ 'requestedDate', 1 ] ] }


GET /api/request?_id=51b8cc2a06859bd418000001 200 238ms - 43.29kb

Comment: but thanks for pointing out the params bit. I think I had it like that initially but changed it to body in my pursuit of getting it working.